# Program can't connect to the IP. Connection failed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, firewall, ipv6

I'm using a program that needs to connect to the ip `200.229.50.3:6900` to work.

But it isn't connecting and it shows this message: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (error code 10060)"

I guess there's something locking the connection. But i dont't know what.

Tried to disable firewall but not worked. This error only occours when i try run the program on a Virtual Machine (VM) (Google Cloud Platafform). My VM runs a Windows 2008 Server R2.

I need a way to make the program connect to this ip.

Any ideia to how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @Moab Did a lot of research. But didn't found something for that.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to telnet to the ip address? telnet 200.229.50.3 6900 it worked for me

Comment: What is telnet? And worked in a VM?

Comment: Do you have a command prompt?

Comment: Yes, i normally use CMD.

Comment: Just found. I need to install Telnet in the opcional features. Imma try. But anyway i already tried pinging the ip, and failed.

Comment: Used Telnet in the VM and this message appeared: "Connecting To 200.229.50.3...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed" It emans i have to unlock port 23?

Comment: also it "Connecting To 200.229.50.3...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6900: Connect failed"

Comment: Have you tried to ping other device on you local network?  Does it work?  Then try pinging an different outside address.

Comment: Check you firewall setting on the devices you are trying to connect too.